# How to create a batch to list SPECYFIC files and directories in a folder

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, directory

I would like to create a batch that output and saves to txt file directories with specyfic files (for example .mp3) At them moment i am using code below which saves everything...

```
echo off
for /r %%a in (*) do echo %%a >> get_files.txt
```

so i get a full directory with file. But i want only **`.mp3`**

Regards

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
(for /r %%a in (*.mp3) do echo(%%~fa)> get_files.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for a FOR loop in this case

```
dir /b /a-d *.mp3 >get_files.txt
```

Type `help dir` or `dir /?` from a command prompt to get a description of all DIR options. The same is true for nearly all commands available to batch - `help commandName` or `commandName /?`.